# Woocommerce - How to display the text on the parent category page in the product archive?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to show the text on the archive page, but only so that it is displayed exclusively on the parent category page. How can I do this?

I don't understand what to do, please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_archive_description` hook for adding text before archive description.

Try out this code in your theme's functions.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'zillion_show_text_cat_parent_only', 10);
function zillion_show_text_cat_parent_only()
{

    $term = get_queried_object();
    if ($term->parent == '0') {
        echo '<div>This is text for product category parent page</div>';
    }
}
```